# How to start a program at a scheduled time if I am logged in?

Tags: startup-applications, scheduled

I want the following behaviour: *if* I am logged in, and it is a certain time, and the program isn't already started, start the program. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Please clarify, the program should start only when you login, e.g. let's say you need the app to start at 16:30, you logged in at 16:25, should program start 5 minutes later after you login or it will never start till you hit into this time frame, maybe on your next login?

Answer (score 2):

Look at this command called `at`
http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/gutsy/man1/at.1posix.html
you can execute commands at a specific time 
Use this to launch your application at a specific time

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this application is a graphical application that requires an X display to connect to, I'd write a script that sleeps for *X* seconds then runs the application, where *X* is the number of seconds until the desired time. Then run this via Startup Applications.

Something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# run at 16:30
h=16 m=30

while true; do 
    # grab current hour and minute
    read now_h now_m < <(date "+%H %M")

    # calculate approximate number of seconds until 16:30 using modular 
    # arithmetics
    (( s = (1440 + (10#$h*60 + 10#$m) - (10#$now_h*60 + 10#$now_m)) % 1440 * 60 ))

    printf "Sleeping %d seconds\n" "$s"
    sleep "$s" && theapp
done
```

That should run the app somewhere between 16:30 and 16:31 each day while you're logged in.

Answer (score 1):

I would write a script to be run by CRON.

To check if a user is logged in:

```
who -a | grep fred
```

Where `fred` is the user name you want to check for.

```
ps -ef | grep appname
```

Will return something if it finds `appname` running so you can check for that.

Make sure that you run the script with the appropriate user credentials (root?)

So, for example here is a bash script snippet that shows testing for the output from the `cmd | grep ....`:

```
#!/bin/bash

if who -a | grep fred > /dev/null; then
   echo "Fred is logged in"
   if ps -ef | grep appname > /dev/null; then
      echo "User is logged in and app is running"
   else
      echo "User is logged in BUT appname is not running"
      # ---- Do stuff here ----
   fi
else
   echo "Fred is NOT logged in"
fi
```

One thing to note is that the way I've coded `grep` means that it does a wild-card search by default so `grep jul` would find `julian` and `july`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use Scheduled tasks with it can you can specify a lot of things
https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gnome-schedule/
download it at apt://gnome-schedule